# Number of elements of order $5$ in $S_7$: clarification

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

In finding the number of elements of order $5$ in $S_7$, the symmetric group on $7$ objects, we want to find products of disjoint cycles that partition $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ such that the least common multiple of their lengths is $5$.  Since $5$ is prime, this allows only products of the form $(a)(b)(cdefg)$, which is just equal to $(cdefg)$.  Therefore, we want to find all distinct $5$-cycles in $S_7$.

Choosing our first number we have seven options, followed by six, and so on, and we obtain $(7\cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3)=\dfrac{7!}{2!}$.  Then, we note that for any $5$-cycles there are $5$ $5$-cycles equivalent to it (including itself), since $(abcde)$ is equivalent to $(bcdea)$, etc.  Thus, we divide by $5$, yielding $\dfrac{7!}{2!\cdot 5}=504$ elements of order $5$.

I understand this...it makes perfect sense.  What's bothering me is:

Why isn't the number of elements of order five $\binom{7}{5}/5$?  It's probably simple, I'm just not seeing why it doesn't yield what we want.

Comment: Why don't you use GAP? Would you like me to give you the code?

Comment: @BabakS.: I have played around with GAP before.  I was coming at this from the angle of it being an instructional exercise though.  Is there a code for finding the number of elements of a given order in a group?  That would be nice to have to check things with in the future, if you'd like to provide me with it.  Thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\binom{7}{5} = \frac{7!}{5!2!}$ is the number of ways to choose $5$ things from $7$ when order doesn't matter. In this case, the order does matter, since, for example $(12345) \not= (12435)$.

This is an example of the difference between the number of combinations of objects and the number of permutations.

Comment: I knew order mattered, but thought it was taken care of when we divide by 5 afterward.  I guess the lesson here is that since order matters we're prevented from using $\binom{7}{5}$ right from the beginning.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AlexPetzke No worries. You're right about when you use the binomial coefficient, after all, $\binom{7}{5} = \frac{7!}{2!}\times\frac{1}{5!}$, it's the "built in" dividing by $5!$ that is what makes it give the answer where order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks!  That made it click for me.  I can see intuitively how the formula works now.  The $5!$ in the denominator accounts for all permutations of our $5$-tuples, whereas dividing by $5$ accounts just for the cyclic permutations, as is appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{7}{5}$ is the number of ways of choosing $5$ numbers, but you still need to take into account the different possible orders.  Given $5$ numbers you can start your cycle with any of the $5$ you choose, then there are $4$ choices for the second number, $3$ for the third.  Hence the result is
$$\binom{7}{5}\cdot 4! = \frac{7!}{5\cdot 2}$$
as you have already computed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm glad you wrote it the way you did - I was trying to find the missing $4!$.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

> g:=SymmetricGroup(7);
>
> h:=Filtered(Elements(g),x->Order(x)=5);
>
> Size(h);

The size of $h$ is the same as other theoretical approaches suggested. It is $504$.

Comment: You're so helpful!